# JavaScript: mouseenter event in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, mouseover, mouseenter

Is there a mouse enter event in javascript(only JavaScript, no jQuery to be used, please)?

When I do this, it gives no response.

```
window.onload = initAll;
function initAll(){
    if(window.addEventListener){
        document.getElementById('container').addEventListener( 'mouseenter', freeze , false);
    }
}

function freeze(){
    console.log("mouse entered")    
}
```

Could someone Please explain me the difference between 'mouseenter' and 'mouseover'? Is 'mouseover' an alternative for 'mouseenter'?

Help Appreciated!

Comment: [MDN Docs, great place to learn: mouseenter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/mouseenter)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1104403/1053938

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130737/mouseenter-without-jquery

Comment: There is a good explanation of the difference between mouseenter and mouseover here: http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/ (about half way down)

Comment: btw don't forget to invoke your function: `window.onload = initAll();` (you are missing the brackets)

Comment: oh really? I don't think we need the brackets there, man!

Comment: Most of the time you can emulate IE's `mouseenter` by putting this code in your `mouseover` handler... `if (this !== event.target) { return }` This doesn't cover all situations. A full fix can be achieved pretty easily I think, but I don't remember exactly how of the top of my head.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't bother with `onmouseenter`, as [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638877/difference-between-onmouseover-and-onmouseenter) states its specific to IE.

> ...Both onmouseenter and onmouseover fire when the mouse enters the boundary of an element. However, onmouseenter doesn't fire again (does not bubble) if the mouse enters a child element within this first element.

Try this for `onmouseover`:

```
yourObject.onmouseover=function()
    {
        //SomeJavaScriptCode
    };
```

Check [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp) for some good info on javascript mouse events.

Comment: So, is there no way to use 'mouseenter' with other browsers?

Comment: Apparently not according to that post. I normally use `onmouseover` anyways. You can use `onmouseenter` if you are using jQuery though, according to the first answer in my first link. http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/?rdfrom=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.jquery.com%2Fmw%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3DEvents%2Fmouseenter%26redirect%3Dno

Comment: That page says "Firefox started supporting onmouseenter in version 10 (January 2012) and Chrome started supported it in version 30 (October 2013)"

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, Mouseover is an alternative to mouseenter. It gives the UI Control of whatever dom element is being accessed.
refer this for further explaination
http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/10/add-event/
[mouseenter without JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130737/mouseenter-without-jquery)

Comment: But mouseover keeps on firing again and again? how to prevent that?

Comment: you could script a handler for that

Comment: @RachelGallen I am not sure what you are talking about.. Can you please give me some lesson/tutorial link?

Comment: basically you code a onmouseout at the same time...to negate the onmouseover

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30500/discussion-between-navneet-saini-and-rachel-gallen)

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

[image]

If you take the example above, everything inside the border is an element, let's call the one on the left with the word 'Name' in it #A. `mouseenter` will only fire when move your mouse inside the border #A. `mouseover` on the other hand will fire when you enter the border, again when you move your mouse past the grey background behind the '1', and again when you move your mouse over the word 'Name'. If you want the event to fire once, use `mouseenter`.

Answer (score -2):

Mouse over is used when you just hover over something. Mouse enter (or mousedown) is to be used when a the mouse is clicked. A full list of javascript events can be found [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html)

Comment: If you read what it says at the link you've posted, you'll see that mouseenter has nothing to do with clicks