# Keep calling on a function while mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, css

how do I keep calling a function on mouseover while the mouse is hovered over an *html* element

**Example:**

```
<script>
    function a() {
        "special code hear"
    }
</script>
<div onmouseover( 'a()')>&nbsp;</div>
```

How can I keep calling the function a while the mouse is hovered over the div instead of having it call the function once.

Comment: @FaceOfJock it muste be `setInterval()`

Comment: you can do this using setInverval when hover over and cleartimeout when hover out

Comment: @DipeshParmar he want it to be executed more than one time , not executed after x secondes

Comment: @FaceOfJock well `settimeout` will work only once after defined time...where as `setInterval` keep calling function after specified amount of time...

Comment: @FaceOfJock [**Read Here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696692/setinterval-vs-settimeout)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript onHover event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262740/javascript-onhover-event)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Events don't repeat automatically. You can use a timer to repeat the command while the mouse is over, but don't forget to stop the timer at the onmouseout event. You'll need a variable outside of the functions to track the timer so it can be cancelled, which is why we have `var repeater` declared separately.

```
<script>
  var repeater;

  function a() ...
</script>

<div onmouseover="repeater=setInterval(a(), 100);" onmouseout="clearInterval(repeater);"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is one possible solution using `setTimeout` (**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/charaf11/jbpUE/)**), it will be repeated every second:

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div id='div'>test</div>
```

**JS code :**

```
<script>
 document.getElementById('div').onmouseover=function(){a();};

 function a(){

   //some code here

   setTimeout(a,1000);

  }
</script>
```

Comment: You can also replace the timeout line with: setTimeout("a", 1000);

Answer (score 1):

## TRY THIS FIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/C4AVg/

```
var pee = '';
$('#poop').mouseover(function(){

              pee =  setInterval(function() {
      // Do something every 5 seconds
                   alert('hi');
}, 1000);
});
    $('#poop').mouseout(function() {
        clearInterval(pee);
});
```

Comment: he is not using jQuery

Answer (score 1):

As others already mentioned calling a function repeatedly can be achieved using [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) and stopping it can be done using [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval).

In case you're looking for a general solution you could use something like this:

```js
function repeatWhileMouseOver(element, action, milliseconds) {
    var interval = null;
    element.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
        interval = setInterval(action, milliseconds);
    });

    element.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
        clearInterval(interval);
    });
}
```

This starts the interval when the mouse is over the `element` and will call the `action` function every `milliseconds`. When the mouse leaves the element the repeated action will be stopped (until you hover the element again).

Just to show a simple application that counts the accumulated (complete) seconds you hovered an element:

```js
function repeatWhileMouseOver(element, action, time) {
    var interval = null;
    element.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        interval = setInterval(action, time);
    });

    element.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
        clearInterval(interval);
    });
}

var counter = 1;
function count() {
    console.log(counter++);
}
repeatWhileMouseOver(document.getElementById('over'), count, 1000);
```

```css
#over {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<span id="over">Hover me (at least one second)!</span>
```

When you run the snippet note that it stops counting when you leave the element, but it resumes counting when you hover it again.

Maybe important to note that [`mouseout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseout) could also be replaced with [`mouseleave`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseleave) and similarly for [`mouseover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover) and [`mouseenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter). They will behave different if the element you attach the handler to has child elements.

---

Just a note about compatibility:

- `addEventListener` is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and before (see [this Q+A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9769868/5393381) for workarounds).
- The `mouseenter` and/or `mouseleave` event are not supported (or supported correctly) in several old browsers. Check the notes about compatibility in case you have to support these (see for example [this Q+A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6130737/5393381)).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is actually the `onmousemove` event, it's a cleaner way to access the `event` object while you hover some element.

```
<script>
    function a() {
        "special code hear"
    }
</script>

<div onmousemove( 'a()')>&nbsp;</div>
```

`onmousemove` event is called while you're *hovering* the element, check [this example from W3 School](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousemove.asp).

And to understand more about this event, [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event) covers much info about it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `setInterval()` function here...

it also gives you the power to call the function in whatever time interval you desire
like: `setInterval("a()",1000);`
here the time is 1/1000 of a second so 1000 means 1 second
you can put this setInterval function in any function say `b()` and call the `b()` function from the div tag:

```
<div onmouseover="b()">
```

Comment: Sorry i am using mobile to type so cant put it in right format

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tId = null,
    time = 100;
$( '#test' ).hover(
    function( event ) {
        tId = setTimeout( function() {

        }, time);
    },
    function( event ) {
        clearTimeout( tId );
    }
)
</script>
<div id="test">test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//
// try the timer factory
//
function timer ( callbacks, delay, fireNTimes ) {

    timer._cb ||
    ( timer._cb = function () { return true; } );

    return (function ( callbacks, delay, fireNTimes ) {

        var
            un,
            timerState = {
                'current-count' : 0,
                'delay'         : Math.abs( parseFloat( delay ) )    || 1000,
                'repeat-count'  : Math.abs( parseInt( fireNTimes ) ) || Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY,
                'running'       : false,
                'interval'      : un
            },

            callback = {
                onTimer: callbacks.onTimer || timer._cb,
                onStart: callbacks.onStart || timer._cb,
                onStop : callbacks.onStop  || timer._cb,
                onEnd  : callbacks.onEnd   || timer._cb
            };

        return {

            ctx: this,

            startargs: [],

            start: function ( /* callbacks_context, ...params */ ) {

                var
                    that = this,
                    args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 );

                ( arguments[0] !== un ) && ( this.ctx = arguments[0] );
                ( args.length  != 0 )   && ( this.startargs = args   );

                this.running() || (
                    timerState.running = true,
                    callback.onStart.apply( this.ctx, this.startargs ),
                    timerState['current-count'] += 1,
                    callback.onTimer.apply( this.ctx, this.startargs ),
                    ( timerState['current-count'] == timerState['repeat-count'] ) &&
                      (
                        callback.onEnd.apply( this.ctx, this.startargs ),
                        ( timerState["current-count"] = +( timerState.running = false ) ), true
                      ) ||
                    ( timerState.interval =
                        window.setInterval( function () {
                                timerState['current-count'] += 1;
                                callback.onTimer.apply( that.ctx, that.startargs );
                                ( timerState['current-count'] == timerState['repeat-count'] ) &&
                                that.reset() &&
                                callback.onEnd.apply( that.ctx, that.startargs );
                            }, timerState.delay
                        )
                    )
                );
                return this;
            },
            stop: function () {

                this.running() &&
                (
                  window.clearInterval( timerState.interval ),
                  timerState.interval = un,
                  timerState.running  = false,
                  callback.onStop.apply( this.ctx, this.startargs )
                );
                return this;
            },
            reset: function () {
                return this.running() &&
                ( ! ( timerState["current-count"] = +( timerState.running = false ) ) ) &&
                ( window.clearInterval( timerState.interval ), true ) &&
                ( ( timerState.interval = un ), this );
            },
            currentCount: function () {
                return timerState['current-count'];
            },
            delay: function () {
                return timerState.delay;
            },
            repeatCount: function () {
                return timerState['repeat-count'];
            },
            running: function () {
                return timerState.running;
            }
        };

    })( callbacks, delay, fireNTimes );

}

var
    tm = timer(
               {
                onStart : function () { console.log( 'start:', 'this === ', this, arguments ); },
                onTimer : function () { console.log( 'timer:', 'this === ', this, arguments ); },
                onEnd   : function () { console.log( 'done:',  'this === ', this, arguments ); },
                onStop  : function () { console.log( 'pause:', 'this === ', this, arguments ); }
               },
               2000
         ),
    el = document.getElementById('btn1'),
    o  = { p1:'info' };

el.onmouseover = function () { tm.start( el, o ); };
el.onmouseout  = function () { tm.stop(); };

//
//
//  start: this === <button id="btn1"> [Object { p1="info"}]
//  timer: this === <button id="btn1"> [Object { p1="info"}]
//  timer: this === <button id="btn1"> [Object { p1="info"}]
//  timer: this === <button id="btn1"> [Object { p1="info"}]
//  pause: this === <button id="btn1"> [Object { p1="info"}]
//
//    etc...
//
//
```