# Keep calling a function while hovering AND moving over an element

Tags: javascript, event-handling, mouseover

I want to detect when the mouse is moving, while hovering over an element.

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544237/keep-calling-on-a-function-while-mouseover/18544275) answer, which uses an interval, but it's not the same. The interval will keep calling the function regardless of whether the mouse is moving or not. I only want to call the function IF the mouse is being moved while on top of the div.

For example, I can obviously add the mouseover event handler:

```
document.getElementById.addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) {})
```

But this only calls the function once. Same with the `hover` event handler.

How can I keep calling the function while hovering AND moving, and then have the function stop calling when no longer hovering (.e.g. blur)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [mousemove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event) event. From documentation: The mousemove event is fired at an element when a pointing device (usually a mouse) is moved while the cursor's hotspot is inside it.

Answer (score 1):

would [`onmousemove`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmousemove_leave_out) event work? it will call the function when the mouse is moving.

[MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onmousemove)

Answer (score 0):

What you described is part of your solution. You can trigger the interval when mouseover event is triggered. The interval will trigger your function.

You can then add the [mouseout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseout_event) event to the same element and stop the interval. This will stop the function from being triggered.

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: The mousemove event was the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Happy to hear you solved your issue! Best of luck